# маштаб изображения при установки на главный экран

Tags: java, android

Делаю приложение с обоями, при установке картинки на главный экран она (картинка) обрезается по центру, как сделать так что бы она не обрезалась?

**Мой код**

```
     private ImageView mImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

    // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]));

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    Bitmap tempbitMap = (BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]));
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempbitMap, width, height, true);
    WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(FullImageActivity.this);
    wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
    wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
    try {
        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

**Ошибки**

```
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method tempbitMap(View) in the activity class onlyspector.myapplication.FullImageActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3825)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: tempbitMap [class android.view.View]
at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:787)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте изменить размер изображения программно согласно размерам экрана перед установкой в качестве обоев [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22938697/3212712):

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
Bitmap tempbitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempbitMap,width,height, true);
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this); 
wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
try {
  wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
  } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Также в манифесте требуются разрешения:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

Comment: Это помогло, но возникли проблемы, пропала полная картинка т.е белый фон и просто кнопка "установить обои" при нажатии на кнопку Картинка устанавливается на главный экран как надо и после приложение критует. поправил код и дописал ошибки в первом посте. Думаю причина в моих корявых руках

Comment: Вы же, надеюсь, не проставляете слушатель нажатий через разметку?

Comment: Все работает, ошибок нету, но проблема с картинкой сейчас, обновил первый пост, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @V01ume, не надо менять вопрос на ходу. Ваш вопрос был о масштабе. Если он решён - отмечайте ответ верным с помощью галочки и задавайте другой.